# how to insert/ extract transparent channel from a bitmap in C#?

Tags: c#, bitmap, transparent

I want to extract the transparent channel from a bitmap to a 2D array, do some things with it, and then return it back to the bitmap.

How do I extract it/ insert it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using [System.Drawing.Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) that has a [PixelFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat.aspx) value of Format32bppArgb.

You'll want to call [LockBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to so that you can operate on the bitmap bits directly.

The returned [BitmapData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instance contains information about the bitmap, including the `Scan0` property, which is the address of the first pixel in the bitmap. The Alpha channel is the most significant byte of each pixel.

Note that `Scan0` is an `IntPtr`. The bits are in a 1-dimensional array. You'll have to write your own indexing code that treats the 1D array as a 2D array. Be sure to take the `Stride` into account.